# Discord PY - i need command for define channel ID where bot will send NSFW

Tags: python, command, bots, discord, discord.py

Hello i need command like $ID=(CHANNEL_ID) to define ID of channel where bot will send NSFW content, i want share and i don't want let anyone edit code, is possible to do it??

```
async def nsfw(ctx):
   check_role = get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='Leader')
   if check_role in ctx.author.roles:
      channel = bot.get_channel(611574273588461580)
      randomlist = [' msg1 ', ' msg2 ']
      await channel.send(random.choice(randomlist))
      await ctx.send('*hint: bot sending nsfw commands only into nsfw channel! check #nsfw*')
```

Comment: Will the bot be a member of multiple servers?  Should each server get its own channel? Do you have any persisted storage already, like a database or json files?

Comment: yes, bot will be on more server and no i don't have any databse or .json files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i'll try my best to answer this

Assuming you are putting this bot on multiple servers, you can send the image or message to NSFW channels only if you tell it to. There are a few ways I can think of right now, possibly way more, but a lil busy right now.

1. Where Author sent the message

   Seeing that you are doing a bot command first thing, we will use ctx for these few. you could always send it to where the author sent the message, but seeing as though they wont always send in NSFW channels, you can check if the channel is NSFW by using an if statement

   `if ctx.message.channel.is_nsfw():`

   This checks if the user is sending the command to an NSFW channel, instead of something like general chat.
2. Custom Channel

   You could always just put a channelID, which is what I see that you have done. Since 
   you want this bot on multiple servers, however, it's best if you find the NSFW 
   channel, by either using the `discord.utils.get` for one instance OR by using a for 
   loop, like

   `for channel in bot.get_all_channels()`

   and then breaking once you find the NSFW channel, and then sending it to that 
   channel found. This way is honestly a lil tedious, but if you want, you can have 
   them specify what channel they want to send it to. Like lets say you have a command 
   to set a string of what the channel is called, or if you want, what the ID of the 
   channel is and save it as an int. Then you could use the bot.get_channel(id) which 
   is what you used above

   If you want them to specify the name and not the id, then that is when you could use 
   the `discord.utils.get` function. I will not go into detail about it, since it is 
   already in the documentation already deeply detailed, however, thinking at the top 
   of my head real quick, it should look something similar to this

   `nsfw_channel = get(bot.get_all_channels(), name="whatever the name of it was")`

   By the way, the name of the channel can be whatever they put as well.

Also would like to say that I don't know what you mean when you say that you don't want anyone else to edit the code? Were you gonna share the file directly with someone, put it on a server? Just a bit confused on why you are worried about it lmao.

Well, hope I helped in some way, my first answer to StackOverflow (hey guys :D ).